# How to implode + add linebreak?

Tags: jquery

I want to display the text on the page with linebreak,

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="content">one,two,three</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(".content").text(function(i, val){
return val.replace(/,/g, "<br>");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but what i get is:

```
one<br>two<br>three
```

Comment: Use `html()`, not `text()`

Comment: wow thank you for fast answer:)

Comment: @futacun Reload the page and check out the snippet. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<br />` is a HTML tag. Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$(".content").html(function(i, val){
  return val.replace(/,/g, "<br />");
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".content").html(function(i, val){
    return val.replace(/,/g, "<br />");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">one,two,three</div>
```